# How to listen to CSS change in Selenium?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I have a div that is a save button that has an awesome font symbol. After clicking the div, a new CSS class `disabled` is added where the opacity is reduced to visually signal the clicking of the button. After the save event the `disabled` CSS class is removed again and the button is fully visible again. If I try to verify this by Selenium naively the adding of the CSS class and the removal is too fast for Selenium, i.e.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".save-button")).click();
```

is working and finds the button and clicks it, but the next find throws a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".save-button .disabled"));
```

It doesn't work with explicit wait neither (I didn't mention for simplification). Selenium is too slow to recognize the change, i.e. the CSS class is removed before the second find started. Do I need something like a listener started before the click event, maybe via JavaScript solutions of Selenium? Any other approach? Looks like threading a wait before is not possible in Selenium.

Comment: Maybe `WebDriverEventListener` could work? But I don't see which method I should use for a CSS change...

Comment: Are you saying that waiting (`WebDriverWait`) for visibility and then invisibility of `By.cssSelector(".save-button .disabled")` doesn't work? You mentioned an opacity change... have you tried waiting for that? What is the intent? Why can't you just wait for the final product? Do you have to detect the intermediate?

Comment: @JeffC Yes the question is about asserting that the change really happened. We had issues that the save button click was not successful, but no selenium exception was thrown (e.g. Stale). We have no other chance but to recognize this very short CSS change to be sure that click happened and we don't not to repeat the click event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium isn't too slow (at least in this case), but the CSS parameter was wrong:

`".save-button .disabled"` with one space means two elements in a hierarchy (`<div class="save-button"><div class="disabled"/></div>` whereas `".save-button.disabled"` would have been correct and is indeed working.

I didn't notice in the first place, because the Chrome inspector isn't that tight and found the div with this theoretically wrong parameter.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments by JeffC the detail that the inspector matched the element with the wrong parameter cannot be true. I verified it with the comment div from this page and the inspector is not matching here. See screenshot below. I won't analyze this further as my Selenium test is working now.

[image: screenshot of inspector with this page]

Comment: I've never found a mistake with the Chrome inspector and I use it almost daily. When it returns elements, expand that collection and click on an element. This will navigate the DOM to the particular element. Once you've done that, you can make sure that it's finding the right element by hovering over the element in the DOM inspector.

Comment: @JeffC Check the CSS specification. The CSS selector ".save-button .disabled" should not match my example, but the Chrome inspector does. It won't call it a mistake, but a loose implementation of the specification...

Comment: What you are referring to is not a "loose implementation", it would be a bug... and that would be a big one. Post a link to the page... I'd like to look at it. I think there's probably another element that matches that locator but isn't the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated my answer with your correction.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by removing all the stuff about chrome inspector. It isn't really relevant to answer the question.

Comment: @kapex Yes I would have put it in the comments, but screenshots are not allowed in the comments, right?